# Java keystore for passwords

Tags: java, keystore

Is it possible to use Java Keystore to store password, particularly for WebServices and such?
I found online information about storing SSL keys, but this is an over-kill for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending on the type of key store, you can create a `SecretKeyEntry` in a `KeyStore`. The SunJCE provider implements a "JCEKS" key store that accommodate secret key entries.

```
static byte[] getPassword(KeyStore ks, String alias, char[] master)
  throws GeneralSecurityException, DestroyFailedException
{
  if (!ks.entryInstanceOf(alias, KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry.class))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  KeyStore.PasswordProtection pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(master);
  try {
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry e = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, pp);
    return e.getSecretKey().getEncoded();
  }
  finally {
    pp.destroy();
  }
}

static void setPassword(KeyStore ks, String alias, byte[] password, char[] master)
  throws GeneralSecurityException, DestroyFailedException
{
  SecretKey wrapper = new SecretKeySpec(password, "RAW");
  KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(wrapper);
  KeyStore.PasswordProtection pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(master);
  try {
    ks.setEntry(alias, entry, pp);
  }
  finally {
    pp.destroy();
  }
}
```

You should be careful to "zero" the passwords as soon as you are done using them, just like I `destroy()` the `PasswordProtection` instance in a try-finally block. Otherwise a memory scraper like that used in the Target breach has a better chance of grabbing a key.

Comment: @DaSh I added some code to show how to work with the entries. Hopefully you already understand how to load and save a key store, and safely prompt for the master password and encode/decode the other passwords from character arrays. The code included already is unwieldy for this format.

Comment: @erickson  What's the best way to secure the keystore password master?

Comment: @erickson I guess I didn't ask the question clearly.  My situation is that the user need to access the KeyStore during the life span of the application.  It would be quite inconvenient to ask user to input master password everytime he accesses the KeyStore.  I'd like to know a secure way to keep the master password in the application.

Comment: @Guangliang there’s not a lot you can do in a Java application to provide extra protection for the password in memory. Fortunately, it’s pretty secure already; if an attacker has access to process memory, you’ve already lost. One thing you should do is make sure that you aren’t duplicating the password unnecessarily. You might consider giving the user an explicit “sign out” capability that destroys the password after they complete some advance operation that requires extra privileges.